# Transparency issue with opengl/lwjgl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am attempting to draw two textures to 3D space that containing transparency.  When they do not overlap they work fine:

[image]

However when one texture overlaps the other the the transparency means that you can see through the one behind:

[image]

I use `GL_SRC_ALPHA` and `GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA` when initialising blending.

Comment: Make sure you have glEnable(GL_BLEND);

Comment: @Balk I don't think you understand the problem :P

Comment: You need to depth sort your translucent sprites from back-to-front. Opaque objects should be drawn first, and ideally they would be drawn front-to-back (but the depth buffer can be used effectively for this purpose and you do not ***have*** to sort opaque objects). You will usually get better performance if you draw opaque objects front-to-back (it helps with depth buffer optimization techniques), but it is not worth taking the time to manually sort them. With translucent objects, you have no choice - for proper blending you absolutely have to sort them.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Thanks, it seems that that's what I'm gonna do :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to either depth sort or use alpha testing:

```
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glAlphaTest(GL_GREATER, 0.0f);
```

which will only draw pixels that have an alpha value of more than 0f. However, this doesn't work for blending transparent pixels. Andon's solution is the one that I use, although I work in 2D and I have to have transparency for smoke effects.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use the `discard` keyword in the fragment shader, as the alpha test is no longer with us. This has the disadvantage of having aliased edges of objects.

Another possibility is to depth-sort the objects and draw back to front. Obvious disadvantage is having to perform the transformations and the sorting in the first place. This can be sometimes avoided if the order of the objects can be determined statically (when the camera doesn't change much). Another disadvantage is overdrawing of the shaded pixels by something different, therefore throwing away performance.

Finally, you can use [alpha-to-coverage](http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=3D&ID=61), where the antialiassing hardware is employed to take care of the transparency. This doesn't require sorting and makes the edges of the objects smooth. The disadvantage is that this is enabled per rendering context and may not be available everywhere.